# Set text color of a textview in a listview item? (Android)

Tags: android, listview, textview

Been scouring this site for any answers, no real easy solution I've found for this. I am creating an Android application that uses an sqlite database to look up a hex value by the color name typed in. I am dynamically creating a TextView, setting its text and text color, then adding it to the ArrayList, then the ArrayList is being added to the ListView. The text shows up in the ListView, but its color property is not being set. I'd really like to find a way to get the text color set for each listview item. Here is my code thus far:

Class Variables:

```
    private ListView lsvHexList;

private ArrayList<String> hexList;
private ArrayAdapter adp;
```

In onCreate():

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.color2hex);

    lsvHexList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsvHexList);

    hexList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In my Button Handler:

```
    public void btnGetHexValueHandler(View view) {

    // Open a connection to the database
    db.openDatabase();

    // Setup a string for the color name
    String colorNameText = editTextColorName.getText().toString();

    // Get all records
    Cursor c = db.getAllColors();

    c.moveToFirst(); // move to the first position of the results 

    // Cursor 'c' now contains all the hex values
    while(c.isAfterLast() == false) {

        // Check database if color name matches any records
        if(c.getString(1).contains(colorNameText)) {

            // Convert hex value to string
            String hexValue = c.getString(0);
            String colorName = c.getString(1);

            // Create a new textview for the hex value
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setId((int) System.currentTimeMillis());
            tv.setText(hexValue + " - " + colorName);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(hexValue));

            hexList.add((String) tv.getText());

        } // end if

        // Move to the next result
        c.moveToNext();

    } // End while  

    adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hexList);
    lsvHexList.setAdapter(adp);


    db.close(); // close the connection
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not adding the created TextView to the list at all, you just add the String to the list, thus it doesn't matter what method you called on the TextView:

```
     if(c.getString(1).contains(colorNameText)) {
        // ...
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setId((int) System.currentTimeMillis());
        tv.setText(hexValue + " - " + colorName);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(hexValue));

        hexList.add((String) tv.getText()); // apend only the text to the list
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!  lost the TextView  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }
```

What you need to do is to store the colors in another array, and when creating the actual list view, set the color of each TextView according to the appropriate value in the list.

To do that, you will need to extend `ArrayAdapter` and add the logic of the TextView color inside.

Comment: Sounds great. How would that look code-wise? Kinda a newbie programmer here. =P

Comment: I don't have a ListAdapter example right now, but see the link below for extending BaseAdapter, the idea is pretty much the same: https://github.com/BinyaminSharet/Icelandic-Memory-Game/blob/master/src/com/icmem/game/BoardGridAdapter.java

Comment: Not exactly helpful. Anyone else?

Comment: I just got home, and found that I do have an example, and it's in the same site, take a look here: https://github.com/BinyaminSharet/Icelandic-Memory-Game/blob/master/src/com/icmem/game/BestResultsAdapter.java  You will need to perform some changes, but the structure should be pretty clear.